# Delphi Generics: TArray.Sort

Tags: sorting, delphi, generics

I am just starting to get my feet wet with this .

```
PNode = ^TNode;

TNode = record
  Obstacle : boolean;
  Visited : boolean;
  GCost : double; // Distance from Starting Node
  HCost : double; // Distance from Target Node
  x : integer;
  y : integer;
  vecNeighBour : array of PNode;
  Parent : PNode;
end;
```

OnFormShow I fill the array :

```
 SetLength(Node,4,4);

 Image1.Height:=Length(Node)*50;
 Image1.Width:=Length(Node)*50;

 for x := Low(Node) to High(Node) do
   for y := Low(Node) to High(Node) do
      begin
        Node[x,y].Obstacle:=false;
        Node[x,y].Visited:=false;
        Node[x,y].GCost:=infinity;
        Node[x,y].HCost:=infinity;
        Node[x,y].x:=x;
        Node[x,y].y:=y;
      end;
```

Now I would like to Sort this array by HCost , so I tried this .

```
  TArray.Sort<TNode>(Node , TComparer<TNode>.Construct(
  function(const Left, Right: TNode): double
  begin
    if Left.HCost > Right.HCost then
      Result:=Left.HCost
    else
      Result:=Right.HCost;
  end));
```

My knowledge is seriously lacking in this thing . I get a error from Delphi

> "Incompatible types:
>   'System.Gerenics.Defaults.TComparison and 'Procedure'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add a [MCVE]. I am not sure of context here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A comparison function has to return an `Integer` value. It is defined like so:

```
type
  TComparison<T> = reference to function(const Left, Right: T): Integer;
```

Your function returns the wrong type.

```
function CompareDoubleInc(Item1, Item2: Double): Integer;
begin
  if Item1=Item2 then begin
    Result := 0;
  end else if Item1<Item2 then begin
    Result := -1
  end else begin
    Result := 1;
  end;
end;

....

TArray.Sort<TNode>(
  Node, 
  TComparer<TNode>.Construct(
    function(const Left, Right: TNode): Integer
    begin
      Result := CompareDoubleInc(Left.HCost, Right.HCost);
    end
  )
);
```

Or if you want to make it even simpler you can delegate to the default double comparer:

```
TArray.Sort<TNode>(
  Node, 
  TComparer<TNode>.Construct(
    function(const Left, Right: TNode): Integer
    begin
      Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Left.HCost, Right.HCost);
    end
  )
);
```

Comment: Hmm, don't like the use of CompareValue. Too risky. Use `function CompareDoubleInc(Item1, Item2: Double): Integer;
begin
  if Item1=Item2 then begin
    Result := 0;
  end else if Item1<Item2 then begin
    Result := -1
  end else begin
    Result := 1;
  end;
end;`

Comment: It doesn't work with the first number greater than 0! `CompareValue(0.0, NextDoubleGreater(0.0)) = 0`. And specifying an epsilon really doesn't work with sort comparison functions. They need to be equivalence relations. Hard to right them like that, certainly `CompareValue` doesn't fit the bill. And no, it's not for another discussion. It's right here, right now. I fixed the code.

Comment: Why would it need to mention inf? And you don't even need to get that cute with `NextDoubleGreater`, try `CompareValue(0.0, 1.0e-16)`.

Comment: As for what I meant about sort comparison functions, consider these three values, under `CompareValue`. 0, 1e-10 and 1e-20. So 0 and 1e-10 are deemed different. Then 1e-10 and 1e-20 are deemed different. But 0 and 1e-20 are deemed equal. That way leads to runtime errors, infinite loops and what not when thrown at comparison sort algos.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan to avoid inifinite loops, the main point for a sort algorithm is that the compare function always return the same result for the same two values, not that the comparison is accurate - but anyway CompareValue() is not to be used in a sort (and it will be much slower than your manual code)

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Not enough to always return the same result for two values. It needs to implement a total order. That's a stronger requirement.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think so: quicksort allows several equal values, and the resulting sorted order will change, but it won't loop. The only requirement is that the comparison returns the same result for two values *in whatever order* (i.e. comp(a,b)=comp(b,a) all the time)

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez OK, I think you are right, as usual. No looping, but nonsensical order of course!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just mentioned `Infinity` because `CompareValue(NegInfinity, Infinity)` results in `0`. I understand your points and would vote for your implementation - forget about `CompareValue`.